# PJSIP Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm trying to run the PjSip on an Android 15 emulator, but I receive the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-104
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.myapp.library.ui.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:300)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:    36 cannot locate '__aeabi_ldiv0'...
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.myapp.library.ui.MyApp.<clinit>(MyApp.java:263)
    ... 2 more
```

On all earlier versions of Android, it's working fine, just on android 15 not.

Initially I received this error:"`Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]: cannot locate 'rand'`", and I found out that I need to build PJSIP with 
`APP_PLATFORM=android-8 ./configure-android`, and now I receive this error.

I tested also on a real device and same issue.
Please help.

Comment: I got the same exception as you. Follow this link may be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745312/unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-cannot-locate-symbol-strtof-referenced-by