# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtof" referenced by "libsupportjni.so" on API <20

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I'm getting the following error immediately on launch, but only for devices running API <20.

**edit: I initially reported this in Android Studio 2.4, and it's still an issue in Android Studio 3.0 stable

```
D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/[[packagename]]-1/lib/libsupportjni.so 0x41b13f30
E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/mnt/asec/[[packagename]]-1/lib/libsupportjni.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtof" referenced by "libsupportjni.so"...
W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/android/tools/profiler/support/ProfilerService;
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41659ce0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: [[packagename]], PID: 7500
              java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "strtof" referenced by "libsupportjni.so"...
                  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
                  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                  at com.android.tools.profiler.support.ProfilerService.<clinit>(ProfilerService.java:44)
                  at [[packagename]].App.<init>(App.kt:25)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:990)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4446)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling, and disable "Enable advanced profiling". This feature is not currently compatible with API <20, and will cause this or similar crashes. This may be fixed in the future, but as of Android Studio 2.4 preview 7, it's an open issue. [Related issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37325209)

Comment: This also works for dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr4" referenced by "/data/app/**/libsupportjni.so" which i got on API 23 with Android Studio 3.0 canary 6

Comment: @Alex I had the same issue and have reported this issue to the Android Studio team: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63756889

Comment: Also in Android Studio 3.0 canary 7: UnsatisfiedLinkError ... __aeabi_memclr4 ... libsupportjni.so on Nexus5 (android version 6.0.1)

Comment: It's still happening in AS 3.0 beta 2

Comment: I'm very frustrated at Google right now. I've been chasing this all day thinking it was a JNI issue (which I don't use). Why not put a damn warning on the option?

Comment: why they don't automatically bypass it for older versions devices, such behavior of studio is so annoying

Comment: This is happening in AS 3.0 stable, brrrrrr. Google, as usual (

Comment: @GoltsevEugene It's disabled for me on AS 3 as default, but I still get that error.

Comment: Nice one! This is replicating in AS 3.0 stable as well

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the app compiled and built an APK, but crashed when you tried running it.  Turning off the advanced profiling fixed it immediately. The problem was it was putting in a copy of libsupportjni.so in the apk for abis that my project didn't support, so on a device that preferred an unsupported abi it would be unable to find any of the other so files it needed. This was in Android Studio 3.1.2, so it still isn't fixed.  My error message was java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader