# Apk never opens on the real device while working well on the emulator

Tags: apk, android-install-apk, android-studio-2.3

I am using Android Studio 2.3.1, and the Android device is Galaxy 6 edge; currently Nougat 7.0.
Even when all I did was creating a new project and adding one more text view, it's not opened (I get "App has stopped" on the device.)
I selected 6.0, 4.2, 4.1, when choosing API, none of them work.
When transfering apk, I tried Google drive and bluetooth of app-debug.apk in the project->app->build->output->apk.
Please help me, and tell me that I am not not meant to be programming.

below is logcat.

```
05-08 03:02:54.305 9785-9785/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-08 03:02:54.842 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.190 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.213 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.282 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.364 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.393 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.562 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.621 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.733 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.842 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.871 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.example.owner.prob-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-08 03:02:55.872 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.owner.prob-1/lib/x86
05-08 03:02:56.032 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-08 03:02:56.447 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean) took 116.175ms
05-08 03:02:56.572 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-08 03:02:57.279 9785-9851/com.example.owner.prob D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                        [ 05-08 03:02:57.285  9785: 9785 D/         ]
                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa9f12400, tid 9785


                                                                        [ 05-08 03:02:57.333  9785: 9851 D/         ]
                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xad1d6b80, tid 9851
05-08 03:02:57.353 9785-9851/com.example.owner.prob I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-08 03:02:57.356 9785-9851/com.example.owner.prob W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-08 03:02:57.666 9785-9785/com.example.owner.prob W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43745313/486312